# Citadel and Fort - For Ranged or Melee Unit?

Tags: civilization-5

I don't know which unit should I put in there? It's nice to bombard enemy by Ranged, but they are too easily to be destroyed, even with +50 or 100% strength. Melee unit, however, can't attack enemies near the citadel or fort.

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Against the AI, I would recommend putting a melee unit there, and leaving a ranged unit behind it. The enemy units will usually not even attempt to attack the fortified units and will try to walk around, allowing you to bombard them with impunity (and they can only move one tile per turn if you place the fort in a good location, which forces them to walk right next to it).

In addition I recommend using a melee unit that receives tile defensive bonus and that can fortify, such as a rifleman. That means 50% for fortification + 50/100% for fort/citadel.

I'm guessing human opponents might be smarter and just constantly bombard the fortified melee unit, but you can usually still hold a few turns - I suggest, in these cases, to have a backup melee unit ready to replace the wounded one.

I've used forts and citadels in the above way to successfully defend against basically unlimited number of enemy AI troops - especially when I was able to have two siege units behind my fortified one. Just be wary of later-era units that can out-range this entire formation, such as artillery and aircraft.

Comment: But in early game, `Ranged units` usually doesn't have `Indirect Fire`, and, a good location for Fort/Citadel is between `Rough` terrains, which prevent them from firing. In this case?

Comment: @W.N. that's a very good point. I'd say an ideal location will be one where the fort is on a hill (for defense bonus) and the ranged unit is sitting on a hill behind it.

Comment: Well, still... my Swordman + Acher were killed by a Knight, although I did have terrain and Fort benefit :(

Comment: @W.N. I guess your mileage may vary... all I know is that in two different games I set up an citadels this way and they were absolutely impregnable (though I ended up losing both games... in one artillery broke me, in the other I lost for an unrelated reason). Anyway, you shouldn't accept this answer if it didn't work for you :)

Comment: I think it's because of my bad luck? The Knight still had 2HP left, maybe in another case, I should have win (that battle). By the way, melee in fort + ranged behind maybe the best formation here.